# Command control for axi data mover block

Tags: microcontroller, spi, vivado, dma, fifo

I am a beginner in microcontroller programming and looking for a DMA block which will be a "bridge" between SPI and CPU ( memory).

I have found AXI Data Mover block in IP catalogue of VIVADO.

Going by the descriptions, this block of DMA is a basic of all blocks. A combination of AXI Data Mover and commands transfer parameters can represent DMA or central DMA blocks.

Axi stream FIFO will fed  with commands. So...I connect AXI Datamover with AXI stream FIFO via AXI4 Stream Interconnect.

**Questions:**

1. How to create my command control? should it be written in VHDL? Edit FIFO block? in C (software)?
2. What are transfer parameters? Interrupt? data threshold? Determining the forwarding address by analysing input data

Comment: What FPGA are you using? A Zynq or something else?

Comment: @stanri I work in VIVADO and use Zynq

Comment: You should be able to connect up the stream to the Zynq PS core and use C on the PS to drive the core.

Comment: eg: https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/tree/master/XilinxProcessorIPLib/drivers/axidma/examples